# Can I do request to URLs with /%/?name=sam?

Tags: http, url, web

I recently noticed that, when I add a %(nor %2d or similar encoding) the request isn't even sent.
I would like to know what is the meaning and practicality of having /%/ in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

`%` is a reserved character in URLs because it indicates a [percent-encoded character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). To include a literal `%` you must encode it using percent-encoding: `/%25/?name=sam`